# How to use clients provisioning profile to publish an IOS app to app store in expo?

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, eas

I'm building an IOS app with expo. And I don't have a paid apple developer account and my customer have a paid individual apple developer account. So because my customer has an individual account I won't be able to upload the app to app store even I was added as a team member. And my customer is not willing to provide me the access to his developer account. So as I know (please correct if I'm wrong) I'm left with only one option that is to inform customer to generate and send a provisioning profile to me and the use it, but I have no clue how to guide my customer to do it and then regarding how to use the profile in expo to publish the app. I searched everywhere but I couldn't find an answer.

**As a summary what I need to know:**

- Is there a better way to publish this app in my scenario than using provisioning profile?
- How to direct customer to generate and send me a provisioning profile?
- How can I use that provisioning profile in expo eas to publish the app?
  (Also I don't have access to a mac)

Answer (score 0):

So, after reading a lot of articles I found out that to use provision profile method we need to use Xcode and keychain app, so ultimately, I need to have a MacBook for this so this doesn't answer my question. But if you have a MacBook, I think this is the best method in a scenario like mine. I have attached the post if you want to refer for this method.
Post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39436362/9188735

But if I'm wrong or if someone knows a better method, please answer this question.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).